# What does [,] mean in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

As in:

```
public string[,] GetHelp() {
        return new string[,] {...things...}
}
```

And how do I search for it in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks all. Its a “Fastest Gun in the West” question. So the accepted answer goes there.

Comment: Great question! I had no idea there even was a `,` operator... C# syntax is fugly at times..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a multi-dimensional array.

Here's the MSDN page for multi-dimensional arrays:

[Multidemensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

That's a multidimensional array.

Not sure what the best way to search for such a thing in documentation is, but you may have found at least the second best way: Ask on SO.

Answer (score 3):

It's a multi-dimensional array declaration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx